# Import failure of s3fs library in AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-glue

AWS glue is not importing s3fs module

```py
import s3fs
```

I expect the library to be imported but AWS glue says

ImportError
:
No module named s3fs

Comment: https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks. But there is nothing given in there.

Comment: Do you have boto3 ?

Comment: are you running this import in databricks? in that case you might want to execute the following:


%sh
/databricks/python/bin/pip install s3fs

Answer (score 5):

AWS Glue jobs come with some common libraries pre installed but for anything more than that you need to download the `.whl` for the library from pypi, which in the case of `s3fs` can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/#files).

Once you have that, upload it to an s3 bucket, eg. `s3://my-libraries/` and reference it in the `Python library path` field in the console.

[image]

This will prompt Glue to install the libraries within this bucket prior to running the script. Note that only pure python libraries are support currently.

Answer (score 0):

s3fs is only included in Glue 2.0 and up. If you are trying to use this in a Python shell Glue job which uses Glue 1.0, you'll have to provide the whl file for s3fs as Sherlock mentioned above.

Here is a list of the default packages for Python Shell jobs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#python-shell-supported-library